# What is/is there a word for singing through your nose?

Tags: vocabulary

I recall there being a word for nasal singing, I might be imagining things, but haven't had any luck finding that word on Google. Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you referring to "humming"?

Comment: I'd read about Bobby McFerrin. If there's a specific name (other than humming), it will be found somewhere around him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the term ["rhinophonia?"](http://gocportland.org/chant_john_sakellarides.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about **nasal voices**? If you are I have some medical jargon for you.

[rhinolalia](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/rhinolalia) is the medical term for this nasal speech. 
This can be further classified into *hyponasal speech (hypo-rhinolalia)* and *hypernasal speech (hyper-rhinolalia)*. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_voice) has a superficial discussion on these topics if you care.

Hope this is helpful.